# Passing Info & Redirecting after Successful jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm new to jQuery File Upload and Javascript in general and have been working on this all day....

I've setup jQuery File Upload on my site. Users will add any number between 1 and 10 files to the interface, then hit the "Start Upload" button to initiate uploading the files to my server. After the files are done uploading, I would like to pass the filename of each file, as well as a few other PHP variables that are defined on that page ($username, $timestamp, etc) to what would essentially be a "redirect page."

On the "redirect page," I'd like to list each of these variables and the name of each file that was uploaded as a confirmation for the user. I also may add some of this data to a database.

I tried playing with the redirect option in jquery.fileupload.js, but it seems to ignore parameters that I insert there. And I don't even know where to start to send each filename to that redirect page.

Would anyone mind pushing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can add a parameter `done` to upload function, in that parameter you can setup the query for the next URL.

But you could do it by sessions which is more secure.

without session:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    var queryString = 'username=<?php echo $username; ?>&timestamp=<?php echo date('U'); ?>';
    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
        queryString += '&file['+index+']='+file.name;
    });
    window.location.href = 'myNextPage.php?'+queryString
}
```

With session you have to modify the file that processes the upload. I believe your scripts work with sessions because you mentioned about username.

Edit the upload class and add session data after the `move_uploaded_file` is called. That way your `done` parameter should be:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    window.location.href = 'myNextPage.php';
}
```

And you can read session information on that page.